# Speeding up the import of DXF files in QGIS

Tags: qgis, import, performance, dxf, cad

I have to import several DXF-Files into QGIS and load them into a database. The files are quite big, around 20 MB or 30 MB large. I started to import the first DXF-File several hours ago and it is still importing.

How can I speed up the Import of DXF-Files into QGIS in the future?

- Maybe uncheck the "expand block references" or "use curves" preferences?
- Or the plugin "another dxfimporter"?

I use QGIS 3.22 (LTR) on a Mac.

[image]

Comment: What if you just drag and drop them into QGIS?

Comment: Is there any way to avoid loading the entire file in QGIS? Could you filter it with Python, R Stats etc.? Are you using QGIS only to convertf the dxf?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend the QGIS plugin [AnotherDXFImporter](https://gis.makobo.de/en_qgis-dxfimport-dxf2shape/) - it is included in the official QGIS plugin repository. Importing DXF is significantly faster and it does a really good job copying the original styles from the DXF.